# How "meta" should we allow our tags to be?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

We already had a chat about [pros-cons](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pros-cons) over [here](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/30), and I can see the reasoning for keeping it around for this site...

But we've also got a [multiple-answers](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-answers) tag that I *really* don't think we should keep around, but <strike>I don't think I/we should consider flat-out removing it without having a chat about this sort of thing first.</strike> This tag is now gone.

We're early in private beta, I know, but I do think that drawing a line around what a "good" meta tag for this site is would be beneficial for the future.

How meta should our tags be?

Comment: See also [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Answer (score 5):

## Do we really need the [comparison](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison)-family tags?

Tags are primarily meant to help answerers find questions that they can answer, but the [comparison](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) family are rather self-evident from the question format. I propose we nuke most of them and use [comparison](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) for questions about something like logical comparison *operators*. (And even then it's a bit unclear!)

Comment: I agree they should go. If we plan on keeping comparison around for the purposes of logical comparison operators... Then we should use comparison-operators instead.

Comment: Which we have [tag:operators] for already

Comment: The comparison tag is gone now. Thanks for bringing it up.